# How would you create a frustrated Fire Wizard who wants to be a doctor but things tend to explode when he wants to heal them?

Tags: character-creation, healing, pathfinder-2e, game-design

I'm considering a new character for a pirates-themed game of Pathfinder 2e. He was born in an island full of inhabitants with inherent healing magical habilities and in which offensive magic is looked down upon. Naturally, that place became famous for its doctors, and prospered.

My character was, however, gifted with fire magic habilities. So gifted, indeed, that he can't barely cast anything else without his fire powers manifesting. But he *desperately* wants to become a doctor... which is a problem, because randomly turning patients on fire is not a very desirable trait.

As a teen, he was going for a walk with his brother when he fell, and broke his leg. Overconfident on his habilities, my character tried to heal it, and the leg exploded. He was deemed unworthy and exiled from the island shortly after.

My character despises offensive magic, despite being really good at it. And desperately wants to redeem himself and return to his island in the future.

How would you implement something like that on pathfinder 2e? My GM is open for any suggestion - including new habilities. I was thinking about a healing hability heavily dependant on the dice and maybe also dependant on wisdom or his level, to mimic him slowly mastering it through the game - lowering (but not nullyfing) the chance of a healing disaster as the game progresses. I would also like if it added a comical factor to the game - a sort of "tension" whenever my character tries to heal somebody, which I think could result in some fun situations for everybody. However, im aware that, if not implemented correctly, it could instead be frustrating.

I'm fairly new to roleplaying games and pathfinder 2e particularly, so I don't think im able to come with a balanced solution for this. Any ideas?

Comment: I like your character concept! But this question is probably too broad for Stack Exchange. You could try refining your question (perhaps asking about Fire spells with a range of Touch, or asking about the balance of a spell you've written) to see if it can get reopened. For very broad build requests, the Pathfinder 2e subreddit might be a better place, or the Paizo forums. Regardless, welcome to roleplaying games, Pathfinder 2e, and RPG Stack Exchange!

Comment: PS: Check out the Flame Oracle - doesn't sound like exactly what you are looking for, but it seems close. https://2e.aonprd.com/Mysteries.aspx?ID=5